# Sendgrid PHP File Attachment 0KB

Tags: php, sendgrid-api-v3

Using the below, I am able to ADD attachments to email from $_FILES posts however, they are 0kb / null attached.

The name and content type seems to pickup without issues? Wondering if anyone can shine some light to this.

I am sending the form type as so:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

My file input from HTML form is:

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file_input_name" id="file_input_name"/>
```

PHP

```
if (array_key_exists('file_input_name', $_FILES))
      {


            $filecontent = $_FILES["file_input_name"]["tmp_name"];
            $filename = $_FILES["file_input_name"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES['file_input_name']['type'];

            $mail->addAttachment($filecontent, $filetype, $filename, 'attachment');

      }
```

I am using the `Sendgrid PHP Library v3`. All parts works besides the file itself. In the docs of Sendgrid, you must specify:

`addAttachment( content, type, file name, composition )`

Comment: Your `$filecontent` does not contain the file content, but only its path & name. If you are actually supposed to pass the file content: `$filecontent = file_get_contents($_FILES["file_input_name"]["tmp_name"]);`

Comment: `I am using the Sendgrid PHP Library v3`...are you? This code looks like it uses PHPMailer instead.

Comment: Yup: use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;

Comment: Ok so if it's not PHPMailer then the question shouldn't be tagged as such

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code as below

```
if (array_key_exists('file_input_name', $_FILES)){
            $filecontent = file_get_contents($_FILES["file_input_name"]["tmp_name"]);
            $filename = $_FILES["file_input_name"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES['file_input_name']['type'];

            $mail->addAttachment($filecontent, $filetype, $filename, 'attachment');
}
```

as `$_FILES["file_input_name"]["tmp_name"]` only returns the temporary file path where as the first argument of the method requires contents of the file.